# How to pass a 'BeautifulSoup.Tag' object inside http post request in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, eval, beautifulsoup, httprequest, http-post

I have a `BeautifulSoup.Tag` object which I want to transfer in an http post request.
Specifically this is a request a task in google app engine would perform.

This is the code:

> taskqueue.add(url='/maintenance', method='post', params={'row': row})

When I receive the request on the other end, the parameter row is a unicode string. How do I get my original object back? As I undersand json eval won't work for this kind of object, so is there another solution Am I compelled to pass simple objects only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. Beautiful soup is kind of an evaluator. So I can send the object's html and the reuse beautiful soup.

I did it this way:

`taskqueue.add(url='/maintenance', params={'element': str(myObject)})`

and then reused soup inside the task itself:

> payload = self.request.get('element')
>
> soup = BeautifulSoup(payload)

Comment: That's definitely the sensible way to go about things.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try python's pickle functions to pass the value by string.
http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Another way will be use memcache.
just store the value to memcache and pass the key to tasks.

for example

```
memcache.set("some_random_generate_key", row)
taskqueue.add(url='/maintenance', method='post', params={'row_key': "some_random_generate_key"})
```

then in the task handlers, just get the value from memcache again. 
(in fact, google appengine also used pickle to store value in memcache)

```
memcache.get(row_key)
```

Comment: memcache is not durable. Use pickle.

Comment: seems very elegant, but I'm getting this error: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/769013-recursion-limit-pickle
OK, I find out the beautifulsoup is not pickleable in some case. :/